# how to find the number of links ina webpage using selenium rc?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc

I am new to selenium.I want to find out the number of links in a webpage using selenium rc. Could anyone help me on this?

Comment: Don't use Selenium-RC; it has been deprecated several years ago. Use Selenium-WebDriver.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But just want to try this using RC so I posted this question.

Comment: Found the solution using Getxpathcount we can get the no of links in a webpage.